# How to echo datas from multi arrayed JSON table?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, echo

I would like to echo my datas from multi array JSON table.

My Code:

```
My JSON table:
[{"name1": 10},{"name2": 20},{"name3": 30}]


PHP:
foreach ($datas as $data) {
$offense_stat = json_decode($data['offense_stats'],true);
echo '
<tr>
  <th scope="row">'.translatePlayerName($data['player_id']).'</th> --not relevant now                                    
  <td>'.translatePositionName($data['position_id']).'</td> -- not relevant now

  <td>'.$offense_stat[0]->{'name1'}.'</td>
  <td>'.$offense_stat[1]->{'name2'}.'</td>
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Maybe you need `$offense_stat[0]['name1']` as you doing `json_decode` with `true` flag as second argument